# Reusable COM interface for select/poll style reactor

Tags: com

Since it's 2019 and I don't like reinventing the wheel, I wonder if there is any COM interface that wraps select/poll for sockets, i.e. streams that may not always be readable/writeable.

The [ISequentialStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objidl/nn-objidl-isequentialstream) interface briefly talks about incomplete reads/writes, but does not include a notification system for when more bytes become available or a description on how short reads/writes are to be handled, and no `[async_uuid(…)]` attribute exists on that interface either.

I can certainly roll my own here, but would like to go with something that already exists.

Comment: Wrong mental model, an interface is merely a contract, it has no prescribed implementation.  Plenty of libraries around that wrap a socket, the odds that such a library exposes its functionality through COM interfaces is not fantastic.  Not anymore these days.  You'd start shopping based on the language or framework you use.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes, that was badly worded, I need an interface that encodes a similar contract (incomplete read/write, callback when a stream becomes readable/writeable). Since both COM and select/poll have been around for ages I'm amazed that there is no "standard" interface in the way that IStream is (ab)used as an interface for temporary storage of binary data, even without the context of COM Structured Storage.

Comment: An interface is not an api.  An object exposed by a library routinely implements more than one interface, IUnknown::QueryInterface() is core.  A callback is a good example, that's an interface by itself.  Necessary because the client needs to implement it.  So you'll never find one that does everything you need in a single definition.